# Why does the python regex.sub method delete \fr?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code:

```
import re
a = '\frac{{P_{\mathrm{0p}}}^2}{P_{\mathrm{0p}}+R} & \frac{31}{30}'

b = re.sub(r'\\mathrm\{([0pr]+)\}', r'\1', a)
print b
```

and I am getting this result:

```
rac{{P_{0p}}^2}{P_{0p}+R} & rac{31}{30}
```

Where is the `\f`?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not delete it, but \f is the symbol for form feed. You have to either escape it with an extra `\` as `\\frac...` or use a raw string by prepending an r as you do on the second string `r'\frac...`

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes have special meaning in Python strings literals ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)).

When you write:

```
a = '\frac...'
```

what Python sees is: *"Create a variable named `a` and assign to it a string which consists of the ['ASCII Formfeed' character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) `\f`, `r`, `a`, `c`, `.`, `.`, `.`."* The form feed is a control character, it's still there, but it's not visible when you print the string.

If you mean to keep an actual `'\f'` in your string, you must **escape the backslash**:

```
a = '\\frac...'
```

This way Python sees *"Create a variable named `a` and assign to it a string which consists of `\`, `f`, `r`, `a`, `c`, `.`, `.`, `.`."*

Or you use a **raw string**, which disables the "backslashes have special meaning" mechanism:

```
a = r'\frac...'
```

Upside of raw strings: It gets easier to use backslashes as backslashes.
Downside of raw strings: It gets harder to use insert special characters like line breaks or tabs.